# Identifying a single dominant number with high probability in a data point array of 4 to 20 numbers

Tags: time-series, mean, spectral-analysis

[Example readings, and second graph identified Actual Number I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQK4G.png)

**EDIT:**  These numbers on the left are **period** time values in micro seconds (us) in the **"time domain"** and they need to be converted to the **"frequency domain"**  Sampling rate was 76800 hz and the total length of sampling was 23682500us or 0.00236825 seconds. The actual frequency I am seeking is 6660.984 Hz (or close to it).

This is the result of a doppler reading of time values that will be converted to frequencies. Would like to find the **dominant** value.  I think **FFT/FHT** may be the solution, but do not think there are enough data points.

Want to arrive to as near as possible to the solution: i.e. **the Actual Number**

**What numbers to expect in the string?:**

- The number of data points will be between 5 and 20. (in the vast majority of cases between 10 and 20 data points)
- The will be long integers (for example: 1359375) that I will convert into fractional with up to 5 decimal spaces (like 135.9375).
- The data line string will always start with values (2 to 6 data points) that are about 10-30% higher than the **Actual Number** and will progressively decrease and settle into a horizontal level line.
- The **Actual Number**’s value will be very close to the values of the data points that are located from the 50% (middle) to 80% part (near the end).
- There will be at least 2 to 6 data points in that area that will be within 5-10% from each other and also very close to the Actual Number.
- The data points will never exactly match each other because they contain up to 5 more fractional digits. So **MEAN averaging** would not work unless able to “round” them up first.
- I believe a **weighed moving average ** would work best. But that’s because I’m not familiar with other statistics options.

**EDIT:**  Added color-coded chart showing the areas of probability that the readings are closest to the actual value I am seeking. [image]

Comment: You should probably ask at stats.stackexchange.net. Your picture suggests that averaging the last $2/3$ of your observations should do the job. (I would say skip the first $6$ but you say you will have between $5$ and $10$.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Thank you for the suggestion for the stats section.  Yes, the problem is that the number of readings can vary between 4 to over 20 and will never be the same number of data points.   It depends a lot on signal strength and environment, etc.